# Variable Content Into jQuery Popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup

My apologies if this has already been answered. There's many jQuery popup answers but none that addressed my specific needs.

I'm looking for direction in regards to making a generic popup window handler which can take HTML and display it. For instance we have a login page which redirects to another URL (a SSO solution). I would like to make a call, grab the return HTML and stick it into a jQuery popup window.

As an aside to that, what would be the proper way to architect that? Would it all go into a seperate 'popup.js' file? Are there any examples of this being done that I can glean from?

In any event, I appreciate any assistance or suggestions to this matter.

Comment: jGrowl can help you with that, it can take any kind of content into their windows, also where are you getting the response from? an API?

Comment: When you say "make a call, grab the return HTML..", do you mean the redirection to the SSO solution is that call, or do you intend to make the call to SSO in some other manner such as jquery ajax?

Comment: Yes, the redirection to the SSO solution is the call. If I'm not mistaken, I can make that call behind-the-scenes, get the resultant HTML and feed that to the Popup window so the user never changes pages. Is that not possible?